# Problems using and LDR to play Audio from SD card

Tags: android, audio, arduino

I've hit a bit of a roadblock with my project. I've tried for hours and can't seem to find out what is causing my problem.

I'm trying to create a box that, when it's closed I can use bluetooth commands and arduino will play a response. 
When you open the box, it will play a unique audio clip.

The problem is, the LDR works fine as in the unique clip plays whenever I open the box, however when the box is closed, the bluetooth responses don't play as expected, they just play a tiny snippet of the unique response from when it's open?
So once I open the box, the unique clip plays and the bluetooth responses work as expected.

I've tried using switch cases and for loops but to no avail.

Your help will be much appreciated!

```
//Coded By: Angelo Casimiro (4/27/14)                                          
//Voice Activated Arduino (Bluetooth + Android)                                
//Feel free to modify it but remember to give credit                           
//PCM library used to turn voice file into a string of text for the speaker.  
//Credit to HighTechLowTech                                                    


#include <SD.h>                    // need to include the SD library           
//#define SD_ChipSelectPin 53  //example uses hardware SS pin 53 on Mega2560   
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 4  //using digital pin 4 on arduino nano 328, can use other pins 
#include <TMRpcm.h>           //  also need to include this library...         
#include <SPI.h>                                                               

TMRpcm tmrpcm;   // create an object for use in this sketch                    
int ldrPin = A2; //declared LDR on analog pin 2                                
int ldrValue = 0; //reading different values from the LDR                      


//declare voice as a string of data                                            
String voice;                                                                  


void setup() {                                                                 
    //Speaker pin                                                              
    tmrpcm.speakerPin = 9;                                                     
    Serial.begin(9600);                                                        
    if (!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin)) {  // see if the card is present and can be initialized: 
        Serial.println("SD fail");                                          
        return;   // don't do anything more if not                             
    }                                                                          
}                                                                              
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------//   
void loop() {                                                                  
    while (Serial.available()){  //Check if there is an available byte to read 
        delay(50); //Delay added to make thing stable                          
        char c = Serial.read(); //Conduct a serial read                        
        if (c == '#') {break;} //Exit the loop when the # is detected after the word 
        voice += c; //Shorthand for voice = voice + c                          
    }                                                                         
    if (voice.length() > 0) {                                                  
        Serial.println(voice);                                                 
    }                                                                          
    //LDR variable defined from analog pin 2                                   
    ldrValue = analogRead(ldrPin);                                             
    //define LDR value ranges and map them to cases                            


    //if voice string is "marco" then playback the sample array                
    if(voice == "*marco") {tmrpcm.play("Polo!.wav");}                          
    else if(voice == "*hello") {tmrpcm.play("Hello!.wav");}                    
    else if(voice == "*where") {tmrpcm.play("here.wav");}                      
    else if(voice == "*who") {tmrpcm.play("Scott.wav");}                       
    else if(voice == "*knock knock") {tmrpcm.play("Who.wav");}                 
    else if(ldrValue > 500)  {tmrpcm.play("Burp.wav");}                        
    voice="";                                                                  

    delay(1);                                                                  
}
```

It might be easier to see in this sketch using switch cases.

Basically, when the box is closed i can see in the serial monitor that case 2 is active which is what I want.
When the box is open, case 1 is active, but it's not playing 'Burp.wav' until I close it again and it switches back to case 2

```
//Coded By: Angelo Casimiro (4/27/14)


#include <SD.h>                    // need to include the SD library
//#define SD_ChipSelectPin 53  //example uses hardware SS pin 53 on Mega2560
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 4  //using digital pin 4 on arduino nano 328, can use other pins
#include <TMRpcm.h>           //  also need to include this library...
#include <SPI.h>

TMRpcm tmrpcm;   // create an object for use in this sketch

//declare voice as a string of data
String voice;
//LDR value Range
const int sensorMin = 100;
const int sensorMax = 480;

void setup()
{
  //Speaker pin
  tmrpcm.speakerPin = 9;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin))
  {
    // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
    Serial.println("SD fail");
    return;   // don't do anything more if not
  }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void loop()
{
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    //Check if there is an available byte to read
    delay(50); //Delay added to make thing stable
    char c = Serial.read(); //Conduct a serial read
    if (c == '#')
    {
      break; //Exit the loop when the # is detected after the word
    }
    voice += c; //Shorthand for voice = voice + c
  }
  if (voice.length() > 0)
  {
    Serial.println(voice);
  }

  //LDR variable defined from analog pin 2
  int sensorReading = analogRead(A2);
  Serial.println(sensorReading);
  //define LDR value ranges and map them to cases
  int range = map(sensorReading, sensorMin, sensorMax, 1, 2);
  Serial.println(range);
  switch (range)
  {
    case 1:
      {
        tmrpcm.play("Burp.wav");
      }
      break;

    case 2:
      //if voice string is "marco" then playback the sample array
      if (voice == "*marco") 
      {
        tmrpcm.play("Polo!.wav");
      }
      else if (voice == "*hello") 
      {
        tmrpcm.play("Hello!.wav");
      }
      else if (voice == "*where") 
      {
        tmrpcm.play("here.wav");
      }
      else if (voice == "*who") 
      {
        tmrpcm.play("Scott.wav");
      }
      else if (voice == "*knock knock") 
      {
        tmrpcm.play("Who.wav");
      }
      voice = "";
      break;


  }
  delay(50);
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: Have you try a synchronous read ?

Comment: @Ôrel i dont know what that is....

Comment: TMRpcm is an asynchronous playback lib. loop() is not stalled by the playback. Use `audio.isPlaying();` to no do anything during playback

Comment: @Ôrel Thank you for taking an interest in this! I really need it done for tomorrow so I appreciate your help. I'll your suggestion a go, have you seen my edited post? Would it work on the switch case sketch?

Comment: Your new code switch the playing,  Burp is now played on lower value, whereas before it was for high

Comment: @Ôrel do you mean switch the audio.isPlaying(); ?

Comment: Sorry, on the first version you play `Burp.wave`  when `ldrValue > 500`. On the second version `Burp.wave`  is played for `sensorMin`

Comment: @Ôrel apologies, im pretty new to this. Yeah that was an error in the first sketch, it is supposed to play when less than 500 but it doesn't. The second version is supposed to play on sensorMin, but it doesn't. I can see in the serial monitor that case 1 is active, but the audio doesn't play until it switches back to case 2...

Comment: Try to add at the beginning of `loop` this test `if (audio.isPlaying()) return;`

Comment: @Ôrel THANK YOU! I had to change if (audio.isPlaying()) return; to if (tmrpcm.isPlaying()) return;   as i wasn't using the audio library and it worked! I would never have known to do this! You're a life saver! How did you know?

Comment: Classic problem of lock free algo

Comment: @Ôrel you wouldn't be able to explain why that solves it or what that line of code is doing could you?

Comment: I am not sure of why this solve. The code I proposed allows to do nothing else than play the file before trying to do anything else.